# Clear recurcive observable from previous results

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using `expand` operator to recursively call provided function.

```
this.getPolyline().pipe(
  expand(({ polyline, same }) => same ? this.getPolyline(polyline) : empty()),
  tap(e => console.log(e))
).subscribe();
```

It is not neccessary to explain all stuff that happend inside component, so for simplify let's say that on every `click` emits `mapPmVertexAdded$` and `mapPmSnap$` observables.

```
private getPolyline(line?: L.Polyline): Observable<{polyline: L.Polyline, same: boolean}> {
  return this.leafletService.mapPmVertexAdded$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.leafletService.mapPmSnap$),
  filter(([{ latlng }, { snapLatLng }]) => latlng.lng === snapLatLng.lng && latlng.lat === snapLatLng.lat),
  map(([vertex, { layerInteractedWith }]) => {
    const coords = layerInteractedWith._latlngs.map((latLngs: Array<L.LatLng>) => latLngs.map((latLng: L.LatLng) => [latLng.lat, latLng.lng]));
    coords[0].push(coords[0][0]);
    return L.polyline(coords);
  }),
  mergeMap((polyline: L.Polyline) => this.comparePolylines(line, polyline))
)}
```

So here is come the thing that totaly breaks my mind. 
Output after **first** click:

[image]

Output after **second** click:

[image]

Output after **third** click:

[image]

It seems that all previous results stayed in stream. I want to have only 1 element in stream. How can i achieve this behaviour?

Comment: one word: unsubscribe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand it correctly, add a first() operator might just stop previous stream in the loop from emitting

```
private getPolyline(line?: L.Polyline): Observable<{polyline: L.Polyline, same: boolean}> {
  return this.leafletService.mapPmVertexAdded$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.leafletService.mapPmSnap$),
  filter(([{ latlng }, { snapLatLng }]) => latlng.lng === snapLatLng.lng && latlng.lat === snapLatLng.lat),
  map(([vertex, { layerInteractedWith }]) => {
    const coords = layerInteractedWith._latlngs.map((latLngs: Array<L.LatLng>) => latLngs.map((latLng: L.LatLng) => [latLng.lat, latLng.lng]));
    coords[0].push(coords[0][0]);
    return L.polyline(coords);
  }),
  mergeMap((polyline: L.Polyline) => this.comparePolylines(line, polyline)),
  first()
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted condition in main pipe

```
this.getPolyline().pipe(
  expand((polyline) => this.getPolyline(polyline)),
  tap(e => console.log(e))
).subscribe();
```

And used `take(1)` instead `first()`